# Simple ways to maintain state across an interal small .net core 3.1 ajax web app/page

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core, session-state, .net-core-3.1

I am have an internal tool used by a few people (no auth needed) and no security issues.

It is a simple tool that updates things using Razor partial views and the FetchAPI.

I am using the lessons in this tutorial ([Partial Page Update with AJAX in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update)) for how to do simple AJAX calls done one after another on a single page. The process
starts when a using clicks a button after `OnGet()` is loaded.

Going through the five or so AJAX calls, how do I maintain some state?

I have a simple object that is made up of various types from `int`, `stings` and `collections` (like `list` and `dictionary`)
that never gets to big.

Looking at this MSDN doc ([Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)), what would be the most ideal why to preserve tate across the AJAX calls?

Comment: Do you need server side state? Or would you be happy with stashing a json string in the users browser? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yeah I thought about that way and did so in the past with full SPA, but was wondering what is the "correct" way to do it server-side in latest .net core?

Comment: Leaning towards something like this: https://www.webtrainingroom.com/aspnetcore/session but not sure on the date of this type of thing or has .net been updated a bit more in 3.1?